# program to print the 5th prime number in a given range. **If the range is short then print 0.**

Tags: java

program to print the 5th prime number in a given range. **If the range is short then print 0.**

Comment: "if range is short" probably means "if there are less than 5 prime numbers in the given range".

Comment: Are you cheating? ;)

Answer (score 0):

If range is short then print zero means that if there are less than 5 primes in the range, print 0.

Also, if you're looking to detect prime numbers, you might want to use something more efficient. Take a look into Fermat's [Primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test). If you're going to be using some massive primes (hundreds of digits) your method will take a very long time. The Fermat test is efficient.

Also, don't use variable names like n1. Why not use firstNum? Then you don't get messy looking things like n1+1.

Answer (score 0):

It means that if there is no 5 prime numbers at least in your range, your output must be 0.

One possible solution is, assumming that your array keeps all the prime numbers in the range, to check your aray before writing the output, if the array contains at least five numbers, that means the range was right, oterwise , the range was to short:

```
if (arr.size > 4) {
  System.out.println(arr.get(4));
}else {
 System.out.println("0");
}
```